# can't earn 'Cooperative novice' in sc2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm trying to earn the Guide One achievement.

The last one I need to complete is the

**Cooperative Novice**
**Win 3 Cooperative games**

I have 2/3, but I don't remember how I got the 2.

I've tried 2v2 melee, 2v2 cooperative agains't ai, but neither has earned me "cooperative game" win.  How do I get my last win?

I'm trying through 'custom games'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind, I'm obviously blind.

It says

'Play Cooperative', in the box above 'Custom Games'

Just in case anyone else is blind... lol

[image]

Comment: I don't blame you; SC2 is kind of unclear and picky when it comes to exactly what type of game qualifies for an achievement and what type doesn't.

Comment: @Brant thankfully the new HoTS interface is much more clear. Not great but leaps and bounds ahead of the WoL UI.